# why Javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im using bracket to create my code and it did run the code.

somehow when i test my codes in w3school and codepen (odepen.io/pen/?editors=101) website it works fine.

any idea?

HTML code (without change the code)

```
<table width="400" border="1" align="center">
 <tr>
   <td><div id="number1">1</div></td>
   <td><div>+</div></td>
   <td><div id="number2">2</div></td>
   <td><div>=</div></td>
   <td><input type="text"></input></td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Check"></input></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

this is JavaScript code. if i run this code in codepen it works fine.

```
//random number appear when start game
var number1;
var number2;

number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML=number1;
document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML=number2;

//Answer
var answer = number1 + number2;
//add click handler with check answer
var checkAnswer = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
var value = checkAnswer.value;
var btn = document.querySelector('input[type=button][value=Check]');


 btn.onclick = function() 
  {
 if (value == answer) 
  {
      alert('You are correct');
   }
 else{
      alert('You are incorrect, the answer was ' + answer);
   }

 document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value = "";               
 document.getElementById('number1').innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById('number2').innerHTML = ""; 
 number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
 number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
 document.getElementById('number1').innerHTML = number1; 
 document.getElementById('number2').innerHTML = number2;

 answer = number1 + number2


};
```

Comment: Are you asking why your code works? Where doesn't it work?

Comment: There is no script element in your HTML so the script isn't being loaded at all. (You've probably just omitted that important part of your code from the question, but its positioning can be significant).

Comment: Please tell us, what you expect your code to do, and what it does instead. Just saying "it works fine" in some environments is not a problem description.

Comment: "It is not working" doesn't give us much to work with - describe the problem.  BTW, most common problem I see is not waiting for the page to load before running - use an onload handler.

Comment: basically, user has to put the answer and when click on the button. it will check if the input answer is right or wrong. then it will generate random number on the next question. you may want to see the code in  codeine ( http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgdBeG)

Answer (score 0):

Sites like CodePen and WC3 create script tags, doctypes, and css links for you. They are intended for rapid development so they leave these repetitive steps out. However you cannot simply copy and paste their contents out and have production ready code.

Your HTML document needs to have a doctype, and a link to your .js file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foo.css">
        <script src="js/foo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      your table goes here
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

why to hard using :

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

get easy to add some id

```
<input type="text" id="theanswer"></input>
```

get the value :

```
var checkAnswer = document.getElementById('theanswer').value;
```